# Problems with array in addChildEventListener (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Integer scores[] = new Integer[10];
int count = 0;
```

I have some data that I want to put into `array`. I put it in **onChildAdded**, but if I need to get the data from the array **out of the onChildAdded**, console shows **"null"**.

> If I will try to get the data of array into **onChildAdded**, it will be
>   success

```
data.child("scores").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        count++;
                        scores[count] = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

int i = scores[1];
```

> **IMPORTANT MOMENT**
>
> For example, If I will use operation **FOR**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        scores[i] = i;
    }

    int i = scores[3];
```

***i* will not be null**

Comment: Has the `onChildAdded` method already been called when you get the data out of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase APIs are `asynchronous`, meaning that each one of those methods: `onChildAdded()`, `onChildChanged()` etc, return immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the Task it returns, will be called some time later. There are no guarantees about how long it will take. So it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. Because that method returns immediately, the `scores` array has not have been populated from the callback yet and that's why is empty.

Basically, you're trying to use a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous. That's not a good idea. You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

A quick solve for this problem would be to move the following lines of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    scores[i] = i;
}
int i = scores[3];
```

Inside the `onChildAdded()` method, where the data is available.

If you need to loop your `score` array outside the callback, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Can you help me with solution of problem, pls

Comment: Sorry, I am beginner in Java and It is a little problematic for me

Comment: The first solution is very simple, have you tryed it? The second is a little bit complicated but you should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: I tried to solve it, but I could not use it in my code, can you help?

Comment: Please see my comments above.

Comment: There one important moment. If I will use callback in onChildAdded, it will be work as much as children have

Comment: What I need. I need to do function, when Firebase completely add children to array. It is what I need

Comment: So, is there the function, which defines that it is the last round of adding child in onChildAdded?